# Why is my background positioned wrong in this simple example

Tags: css, html

When I test this about 30% of the lower part of the image is being positioned at top right.

I can't understand why.

If I for example positioned top left or top right it works fine.

It never works if I give positioned as in this example bottom right or bottom left.

If I give positioned bottom left then again about 30% of the lower part is being positioned at top left.

Here is the complete markup and css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset=utf-8" />
      <title></title>
      <style type="text/css" media="screen">
         body
         {
            background-image:url(uppsala.jpg);
            background-position: bottom right;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
         }
      </style>
   </head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is at the bottom right of the body element, but the problem is that the element isn't as tall as you think it is so it looks like it's in the wrong place.

Add this to the CSS rules:

```
body, html {
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Your anser works but I don't understand what you mean. If I only use my code nothing is shown at the bottom right only the 30% at the top right is shown. Can you explain in a better way what you mean.

Comment: The `<body>` tag doesn't automatically cover the entire viewscreen, i.e. its height is not automatically 100%. You can see what I mean if you add background-color to the body in your code.

Comment: A background-color fill the whole viewport but when I use border:1px solid red; I can see what happen. The image is actually at the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare height in css rule

```
body,html
         {
            background-image:url(uppsala.jpg);
            background-position: bottom right;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            height:100%;
         }
```

Comment: This is not enough, the `html` must be set to `height:100%` as well.